# Draft and Helm vs Ksonnet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, ksonnet

As I understand all of these tools [Draft](https://draft.sh/),[Helm](https://helm.sh/) and [Ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/) have overlapping functionality such as creating a chart as well as deploying kubernetes configurations.

*I understand that purpose of these tool would be to describe and configure the application as well as the k8s environments.*

> By using Draft we can create Dockerfile, Chart. Nevertheless we can do same thing with Helm and Ksonnet.

*My question is If these components create a pipeline in CI/CD then what will be the order?*

for example,

**draft -> ksonnet > helm** 
or

**draft -> helm -> ksonnet**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In short, **draft** and **helm** are more or less complimentary and **ksonnet** is orthogonal, specifically providing an alternative to **helm**.

In elaborating I will split my answer up into three major sections, the first of which describes how **draft** and **helm** interact, the second describing how **ksonnet** is orthogonal to the others, and finally a section explaining how I understand these with respect to CI/CD.

## Helm & Draft

Helm and Draft are complimentary in the sense that Helm, which can be considered to be a package management system for Kubernetes, provides a portion of the functionality offered by Draft which itself is essentially a Kubernetes application development tool.

The relationship between Draft and Helm can be summarized by pointing out that in pursuit of its goal of simplifying Kubernetes application development, Draft produces a Helm chart using metadata inferred from your current application type (more about that below) if one does not already exist or uses and existing one in order to deploy/update a development version of your application without you having to know anything about how it does that.

### Helm for Kubernetes Package Management

As mentioned previously, Helm is a package management system for Kubernetes-based applications. It provides the following features:

- A templating approach for defining Kubernetes manifests (called "charts")
- Package management, including a basic package repository service to host released packages.
- Application lifecycle management including deploy, update, and purging of Helm applications
- Package dependencies

Helm takes a templated YAML approach to parameterizing Kubernetes manifests and allows values to be shared and overridden between dependent packages. ie, supposed Package A depends on Package B; Package A can re-use configuration values set on Package B and it can override those parameters with values of its own. Values for all packages in a given deployment can also be overridden using the Helm command line tool.

Also worth mentioning is the fact that Helm depends on the availability of its cluster-side component named "Tiller" to actually do the work of reifying templates and deploying the generated Kubernetes manifests to the cluster.

### Draft for Kubernetes Application Development

The aim of Draft is to [dramatically simplify development of Kubernetes applications](https://github.com/Azure/draft/blob/master/docs/reference/dep-002.md#user-personas-and-stories) by being quickly building and deploying the Helm charts/packages and corresponding docker images necessary to run a project -- provided that the following exist:

- A Kubernetes cluster
- Helm's Tiller pod installed in the Kubernetes cluster
- A Docker registry

The [draft installation guide](https://github.com/Azure/draft/blob/master/docs/install.md) provides details for getting these pieces set up to try it out yourself.

Draft also builds on Helm by providing a high-level "packaging" format that includes both the application helm chart and the Dockerfile, the latter giving it the ability to build docker images.

Finally, it has built-in support for specific programming languages and will to a limited extent attempt to infer which programming language and framework(s) you are using when initially creating a new Draft project using `draft create`.

## Ksonnet for Kubernetes Package Management

As mentioned previously, Ksonnet is orthogonal in many ways to Helm, providing essentially the same features with respect to package management wrapped in different terminology -- see its [core concepts documentation](https://ksonnet.io/docs/concepts). It's worth noting that it is not compatible with nor does it address the same concerns as Draft.

I say that Ksonnet and Helm are orthogonal because they take mutually incompatible approaches to generating and deploying Kubernetes manifests. Whereas Helm uses templated YAML, Ksonnet generates Kubernetes manifests using a ["data templating" language called Jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/). Also, rather than conceiving of "dependent" packages as is the case with Helm, Ksonnet blurs the line between dependent services by representing them as composable "prototypes". Finally, rather than depending on a cluster-side application that reifies and deployes manifest templates, Ksonnet has an `apply` subcommand analogous to `kubectl apply`.

## CI/CD

So where do these pieces fit into a CI/CD workflow? Well since there are essentially two mutually incompatible toolsets, let's consider them on a case-by-case basis:

### Draft + Helm

According to [the Draft design Q&A section](https://github.com/Azure/draft/blob/master/docs/reference/dep-002.md#qa), it is meant only as a developer tool intended to abstract much of the complexity of dealing with kubernetes, helm, and docker from developers primarily interested in seeing their application run in a development cluster.

With this in mind, any CD approach involving this set of tools would have to do the following:

- Build docker image(s) using the `docker` CLI if necessary
- Build Helm package(s) using the `helm` CLI
- Deploy Helm package(s) to Helm repository using the `helm` CLI
- Install/update Helm package(s) on the appropriate staging/prod Kubernetes cluster(s) using the `helm` CLI

### Ksonnet

The Ksonnet CD workflow is somewhat abbreviated compared to the `helm` workflow above:

- Build docker image(s) using the `docker` CLI if necessary
- Apply the Ksonnet manifest using the `ks` CLI

Whereas with Helm you would deploy your applicat's package to a Helm registry for re-use, if your Ksonnet manifest contains [re-usable prototypes](https://ksonnet.io/docs/concepts#prototype) that might be of use to another Ksonnet-based application you would want to ensure it is available in a git repo as described in the [Ksonnet registry documentation.](https://ksonnet.io/docs/concepts#registry)

This means that how Ksonnet definitions are dealt with in CI/CD is largely dependent on which git repo(s) you decide to store them in and how they are structured.

Comment: Hi, @Wayne, Thanks for the answering the question. It seems that question is on hold for being generic. Thus, I have edited the question to be more precise and specific. I hope now It can be reopened again.

Comment: Answer should probably be updated with ksonnet development being abandoned